Pinned items to Windows 10 taskbar opens the folder of the executable file instead of launching the executable file
Problem Description

When I click on any pinned item on the taskbar, which targets an executable file (*.exe), it opens the folder containing the target executable file instead of directly launching the executable file.
To be more precise: When I do left click on this kind of pinned item, it opens the explorer.exe with the folder containing the target executable file, and the executable file is selected in the view.
This happens if I pin, for example: firefox.exe, chrome.exe, winamp.exe, smplayer.exe or vlc.exe. Just with any *.exe file.
Something curious I've noticed is that If I pin a Windows Registry Script File (*.reg), when I click on the pinned item, it opens the folder C:\Windows with the regedit.exe file selected in the view, instead of opening the folder where the *.reg file is and with the *.reg file selected in the view, like happens to me with pinned *.exe files.
That behavior leads me to think that maybe shell file extension associations could have something to do with the issue, but I don't know where to start looking in the registry that could be related to this problem.
Notes:

I'm using Windows 10.0.19045.2006 (Codename: 22H2) x64, but I'm suffering this issue since many prior Windows 10 versions, many years ago.

The issue described is not happening with Universal Windows Application (UWP), apps like Settings, Windows Store, Sticky Notes, Calculator, Calendar, etc., they are being launched as expected.


To the question: Are you pinning shortcuts, or are you dragging them onto the taskbar?. It does not matter. The behavior is the same in both cases.
What I've tried?

Researching the same question over Internet, I only have found this unsolved question (and with an odd answer about mouse configuration that of course it has nothing to do with the issue described by the OP).
I tried un-pinning and re-pinning the apps but the behavior does not change.
I've tried reinstalling Windows 10, but anyway this issue happens to me after a fresh Windows 10 installation.
Note: I use NTLite to remove bloatware and components that I don't require to be present in my Windows 10 ISO, before it being installed. But I can't imagine any removed component that can cause this strange behavior. And also, note that the other user whose question I linked, he just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10, so this points that the root of the problem should not be related to "modding" the installation components in a Windows 10 ISO.

"...this points that the root of the problem should not be related to "modding" the installation components in a Windows 10 ISO."  We are always glad to help, but that isn't necessarily true.  The problem you described is very unusual, and it's unlikely to be a coincidence that you have modified the standard Windows 10 installation ISO file before utilizing it.

@Run5k Thanks for comment. In any case, asking for help or support for modded Windows installation is legit in superuser community?. I am very cautious when removing components. I think this issue is not caused by a missing component, but rather something (a registry value?) that is missing in the registry configuration (related to pinned items) after component removals. I don't know...

Hopefully someone who is a better Windows guru than I am can chime in and help you, but it's safe bet that the NTLite modifications caused this.  At the risk of asking an obvious question, have you already considered performing a real fresh install of Windows 10 and then carefully removing unwanted elements afterwards using the built-in GUI?  It seems like that would be much more prudent.

Removing each desired components, one by one, with a system restart after each removal, in a virtual machine doing drive snapshots, all this in order to try determine after which component removal this taskbar problem is being manifested, it could took me very, very long. That is something I have preferred not to do for several years. But if I have no other choice, that is, if I do not find a convincing answer to my question, I will have to follow the procedure described, although it may only help me to determine which component is causing this, but it may not help me to solve it. Thank you.
